# Any Dictionary Definition API for Java?

Tags: java, api, spell-checking, definition

Im trying to find a Dictionary Definition API for java, but can't seem to find any that works without any internet connection. Does someone know any API that might be useful? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [ukp_jwktl](http://www.ukp.tu-darmstadt.de/software/jwktl/)

> Wiktionary is a multilingual, web-based, freely available dictionary,
>   thesaurus and phrase book, designed as the lexical companion to
>   Wikipedia. Lately, it has been recognized as a promising lexical
>   semantic resource for natural language processing applications.

**Example Usage:**

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
        DBConfig db = new   DBConfig("localhost/uby_database","com.mysql.jdbc.Driver","mysql","user", "password", true, false);
        Uby uby = new Uby(db);
        Lexicon lex = uby.getLexiconByName("WiktionaryEN");
        List<LexicalEntry> entries = uby.getLexicalEntries("align", EPartOfSpeech.verb, lex);
        for (LexicalEntry le : entries) 
        {
                for (Sense s: le.getSenses())
                {
                        System.out.println("Wiktionary Sense:"+s.getDefinitionText());
                        List<SenseAxis> alignedSenses = uby.getSenseAxisBySense(s);
                        if(alignedSenses.size()>0)
                        {
                                for(SenseAxis axis : alignedSenses)
                                {
                                     String definition =  axis.getSenseOne().getDefinitionText();
                                     if(definition.length()==0)
                                     {
                                        definition = axis.getSenseOne().getSynset().getDefinitionText();
                                     }
                                     System.out.println("Aligned Sense:" +definition);
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}
```

[google_code_ApiTutorial](http://code.google.com/p/uby/wiki/ApiTutorial)

Hope, it'll help you.

Answer (score 0):

What sort of capabilities are you looking for from the API?  For spell checking, consider [Jazzy](http://jazzy.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Well, Im mostly looking for definitions, such as String definition = SomeLibraryName.defineWord("apple");